# Javascript sliding element performance

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
(function() {

        window.onscroll = function () {
            var sideBars = document.getElementsByClassName("sideBar");
            var y = window.pageYOffset;
            var threshold = 200;
            var marge = 15;
            if(threshold - y >= marge) {
                for(var i=0; i<sideBars.length; i++) { sideBars[i].style = "top: " + (threshold - y) + "px ;"; }
            } else {
                for(var i=0; i<sideBars.length; i++) { sideBars[i].style = "top: " + marge + "px ;"; }
            }
        };

    })();
```

```css
.sideBar { position: fixed; top: 200px; width: 300px; background-color: lightgreen; }

#sideBarLeft { left: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="sideBarLeft" class="sideBar">
  <p>Quack.</p>
</div>
<div style="height: 1800px; background-color: yellow"></div>
```

I made a small function to slide an element as the user scroll the page in pure Javascript.

```
(function() {

        window.onscroll = function () {
            var sideBars = document.getElementsByClassName("sideBar");
            var y = window.pageYOffset;
            var threshold = 200;
            var marge = 15;
            if(threshold - y >= marge) {
                for(var i=0; i<sideBars.length; i++) { sideBars[i].style = "top: " + (threshold - y) + "px ;"; }
            } else {
                for(var i=0; i<sideBars.length; i++) { sideBars[i].style = "top: " + marge + "px ;"; }
            }
        };

})();
```

It perfectly works, but the browser seems to become slower and slower as the user scroll the page. I suspect there is a memory leak somewhere or something wrong but I can't figure what since I am quite not a JS expert

Can some of you enlighten me with this issue ?

(tried with mozilla firefox 38.0.5)

The stackoverflow snippet semms to not reproduce the problem.

**EDIT**

Ahmed suggested to use translateY CSS function instead of resetting the "top" property. This way, it works like a charm :

```
(function() {

    window.onscroll = function () {
        var sideBars = document.getElementsByClassName("sideBar");
        var y = window.pageYOffset;
        var origin = 200;
        var marge = 15;
        var offset = origin-y >= marge ? -y : marge-origin;

        for(var i=0; i<sideBars.length; i++) { sideBars[i].style.transform = "translateY(" + offset + "px"; }

    };

})();
```

Comment: Create a jsFiddle to show Your html structure and css

Comment: I am also not a JS expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Marcos answer, every time user scrolls, the `top` is reset and a *heavy paint* occur. You should use `translate`.

You can read more here https://css-tricks.com/tale-of-animation-performance/

Comment: I used translate in the code instead of resetting the "top" property. It worked like a charm. 

I'll edit my question with my new code.

Answer (score 0):

The onScroll event fires tons of times when a user resize or scroll the page. You can add a deboucer to the function, is a lot of them, but I recommend you to use the underscore debounce function:

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Good luck

## EDIT

I see your code again and you use for() with the limit of sideBars length . What is the maximum number of this variable?

Comment: sideBars.length was 1 during my test

Comment: Ok, this is not the problem. If you add debouncer you solve it

Answer (score 0):

Avoid redeclaring static variables within your loop and 
[Throttle](https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls) your function to only run every n milliseconds:

```js
(function() {    
    var sideBars = document.getElementsByClassName("sideBar"),
        threshold = 200, 
        marge = 15,
        freq = 25;//millisecond frequency for throttle (try increasing this to see it working)
    
    window.onscroll = throttle(function(){
        var y = window.pageYOffset,
            l = sideBars.length,
            t = (threshold - y >= marge) ? (threshold - y) : marge;        
        for(var i=0; i<l; i++) {
            sideBars[i].style.top =  t+"px";
        }
    },freq);
    
})();


function throttle(fn, threshhold, scope) {
  threshhold || (threshhold = 250);
  var last,
      deferTimer;
  return function () {
    var context = scope || this;
    var now = +new Date,
        args = arguments;
    if (last && now < last + threshhold) {
      // hold on to it
      clearTimeout(deferTimer);
      deferTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        last = now;
        fn.apply(context, args);
      }, threshhold);
    } else {
      last = now;
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }
  };
}
```

```css
html, body {margin:0; padding:0;}
.sideBar { position: fixed; top: 200px; width: 300px; background-color: lightgreen; }

#sideBarLeft { left: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="sideBarLeft" class="sideBar">
  <p>Quack.</p>
</div>
<div style="height: 1800px; background-color: yellow"></div>
```